# Is it possible to trigger a script on a notification center notification?

Tags: terminal, applescript, notifications

I'm trying to hook into a "finished" event from a program that doesn't provide any native way to do it.  It does, however, post a notification to the notification center.  So I'm looking for a way to monitor notifications and run a script whenever my computer shows one, preferably with the notification context available.

Comment: AppleScript, generally speaking, cannot monitor events, and it has no way of reading notifications.  Have you scoured the *Console* logs (both systemwide and app-specific) to see what messages are sent to the system when the program has finished its task ?

Comment: @CJK - thanks.  No requirement for this to be applescript, perfectly happy with any solution I just tagged it as applescript since that was my best guess :)